# If $B=P^{-1}JP$ then $B^k=P^{-1}J^kP$?

Tags: matrices

Let $B$ a matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ and $J$ be a jordan matrix for $B$. Then we have  $B=P^{-1}JP$. How to prove that $B^k=P^{-1}J^kP$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use induction. It's obviously true for $k = 1$ (by definition). Assume it's also true for some $k$, i.e.
$$
B^k = P^{-1} J^k P
$$
Now, consider
$$
B^{k+1} = B^k B = P^{-1}J^k P B
$$
Now, use the expression that's Jordan decomposition, then
$$
B^{k+1} = P^{-1}J^k P P^{-1} J P = P^{-1}J^{k+1} P
$$
so it's also true for $k+1$, i.e. according to the principle of mathematical induction, it's true for all $k \in \mathbb N$.